# How to control peek to treat the last element differently?

Tags: java, string, java-8, java-stream

I have a stream of characters like

```
"abcd".chars()
```

I am using peek to print out stream like this

```
"abcd".chars().peek(e->System.out.print(e + ":"))
```

The only problem is that it print out as

```
a:b:c:d:
```

I would like to replace the last colon with newline, but don't know how to do that, anyone could help?

Comment: Does this compile?

Comment: what is the expected output?

Comment: expect to have a:b:c:d

Answer (score 5):

Using the `joining` collector is another option:

```
String result = Arrays.stream(string.split(""))
                      .collect(Collectors.joining(":"));
```

or:

```
String result = Pattern.compile("")
                       .splitAsStream(string)
                       .collect(Collectors.joining(":"));
```

if you actually want a new line then use this overload of the `joining` collector

```
Collectors.joining(":","","\n")
```

Comment: @YCF_L appreciated :). if the OP just wants "a:b:c:d" without a new line as the suffix then your approach of `String = String.join(":", string.split(""));` is the way to go for me but if they actually want the new line suffix as mentioned then i'd just use the overload `Collectors.joining(":","","\n")` as it's simpler and more readable than the for loop stuff.

Comment: I agree @Aominè :)

Comment: @Aominè I like this +1 (the last code snipped), the downside is that simply for printing this needs to concatenate them to a new String...

Comment: @Eugene Appreciated! :). I guess it varies from person to person but personally I think creating _one extra_ new string is something you should not think/worry about? especially in this specific example.

Comment: @Eugene Yes, maybe if the stream's source is huge in size then it would take more time to build the string up and also requires the allocation of a new string. So, I do get your point ;-)

Answer (score 4):

There's likely a duplicate or two out there, but if you don't specifically need to use `peek()`, just do something like:

```
String str = "abcd";
char[] arr = str.toCharArray();
for (int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) {
    System.out.print((i == str.length() - 1) ? arr[i] + "\n" : arr[i] + ":");
}
```

**Output:**

> a:b:c:d

Answer (score 4):

It's not easy to achieve what you want, because you don't have a way to get the `index` in `peek()`. If you insist to use peek I would like to use this :

```
String string = "abcd";
AtomicInteger count = new AtomicInteger(0);
string.chars()
        .peek(e -> {
            System.out.print((char) e);
            if (count.incrementAndGet() != string.length()) {
                System.out.print(":");
            } else {
                System.out.println();
            }
        })...
```

**Outputs**

```
a:b:c:d
```

---

Note you still have to use a Terminal Operation after `peek` for example `sum()`

---

Or more easier you can use `String.join` like so :

```
String string = "abcd";
string = String.join(":", string.split(""));
```

Answer (score 2):

The short answer is: you can't.

Streams are meant for possible parallelized computation on a possibly infinite amount of elements. Thus you dont have access to an `index` (would the index be the position of the element in the data set or the number of calls to the computation in a parallel stream, where order isn't guaranteed?) or to a `size` (infinity).

For controlled traversal you can however convert the stream using [BaseStream#iterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#iterator--) or [BaseStream#spliterator()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/BaseStream.html#spliterator--)

By keeping track of the position externally you cut the possibility to parallize your computations and by referencing the data source of the stream you limit your code to work with non-infinite data streams. Either way it should give you a hint, that Streams are not the right tool for the thing you try to achive.

Answer (score 1):

You can try and use `IntStream.range` :

```
@Test
public void printChars() {
    String str = "abcd";
    IntStream.range(0, str.length())
            .mapToObj(i -> str.charAt(i) + (i < str.length()-1 ? ":" : "\n"))
            .forEach(System.out::print);
}
```

Output:

```
a:b:c:d
```